# Lorentz generators on Fock space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, poincare-symmetry

Consider a free massive relativistic scalar field in $d+1$ dimensions. Its Hilbert space can be taken to be the bosonic Fock space on $\mathfrak h = L^2(\mathbb R^d)$:
$$\mathcal F = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{+\infty} S^n\mathfrak h.$$
On this space we have creation-anihilation operators corresponding to each $1$-particle state. This is usually written in terms of the $3$-momentum eigenstates $|\vec p\rangle$ so we get operators $a_{\vec p}$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
[a_\vec{p},a_{\vec q}] &= [{a_\vec p}^\dagger,{a_\vec q}^\dagger] = 0 \\
[a_\vec p,{a_\vec q}^\dagger] &= (2\pi)^d \delta^{(d)}(\vec p -\vec q).
\end{align}
The (normal ordered) Hamiltonian is then:
$$H = \int \frac{\text d^d p}{(2\pi)^d} (\vec p ^2 +m^2)^{1/2}{a_\vec p}^\dagger a_\vec p.$$
Likewise, we get the total $3$-momentum operators:
$$P^i = \int \frac{\text d^d p}{(2\pi)^d}\vec p^i{a_\vec p}^\dagger a_\vec p.$$
Together with $P^0 = H$, the are the generators of space-time translation. My question is the following:
**What are the expressions of the generators $M_{\mu\nu}$ of Lorentz transformations in this formalism ?**

I haven't found these in textbooks. In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/728489/), we have the expression of the commutator of the boost generators $K_i$ with a creation operator,
$$[K_i,\alpha_p^\dagger]=-iE_p\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\alpha^\dagger_p$$
but this does not tell us the action of $K_i$ on a state of the Fock space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at (3-54) of the basic popular text of Itzykson & Zuber.
Unfortunately, they use an oscillator normalization different than yours, which appears to follow P&S, so I cannot vouch for a single sign or measure in my crude translation below:
$$ \Large
M_{0j}= i\int\! \frac{\text d^3 p}{(2\pi)^d}~~ {a_\vec p}^\dagger E_p\partial_{p^j} a_\vec p \\ \Large
M_{jl}= i\int\! \frac{\text d^3 p}{(2\pi)^d}~~ {a_\vec p}^\dagger ( p_j\partial_{p^l}- p_l\partial_{p^j})  a_\vec p ~.
$$
You may have to fix/fuss signs and prefactors  to your satisfaction yourself; but it should be evident how the commutators of the above [Jordan map structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) yield what you wish, in terms of the Lie algebras and the action on oscillators, hence states, such as you wrote down.

(The more tasteful exercise is to work out $M^{\mu\nu}\sim \int d^3x (x^\mu T^{\nu 0}-x^\nu T^{\mu 0})$ in terms of field operators, and then convert to the above. Cf (2-63) of Paul Roman's *Introduction to QFT* book, 1969.)